# How to enable block editor in "Traveler" wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I want to enable the " Gutenberg" editor. Currently, the theme is using " classic editor". I have installed the "Gutenberg[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxaSM.jpg)" plugin but it is not working. It seems that the theme by default support "Classic editor" but I want to overwrite it and want to use the latest " block editor " of Wordpress.

The theme I am using is " Traveler"
Wordpress version 5.7

Answer (score 0):

1-example.com/wp-admin/plugins.php;
2-Deactivate classic editor

Answer (score 0):

Try to deactivate classic editor plugin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).